# In JavaScript, how to use Xpath for String in any variable

Tags: javascript, xpath, document.evaluate

This code works.
But It's not what I want.

```
<div>XPath example</div>
<script>
const result = document.evaluate('//div', document, null, 6, null);
console.log(result.snapshotItem(0));
</script>
```

I want to use Xpath for strings from outside , but the following code is Null.

```
<script>
var string = "<div>XPath example</div>";
var doc = new DOMParser();
var htmlstring = doc.parseFromString(string, "text/html");
const result = htmlstring.evaluate('//div', document, null, 6, null);
console.log(result.snapshotItem(0));
</script>
```

How can I use Xpath in Javascript for a string get from the outside?

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `document` as the context node, when you should be passing `htmlstring`:

```
const result = htmlstring.evaluate('//div', htmlstring, null, 6, null);
```